# Getting IntCtrl and NumCtrl to return value after button(wx.Button) widget is pressed

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

This is my first gui in `wxPython`, so I apologize if this comes of as something too elementary to deem a post.

I have a gui that is sending values to a serial controller, after the decimal value is converted to a hex value and sent over as a string. My gui contains a few `IntCtrl` and `NumCtrl` inputs. When a user presses a button corresponding to one of the inputs, the box should return whatever value it contains at that moment.

so let's say I have the following `NumCtrl` & Button widgets:

```
flt1 = NumCtrl(self, pos, size)
flt1.GetValue()
btn1 = wx.Button(self, label, pos, size)
```

I seem to be getting confused as to how to bind the button(btn1) press to grab the value in a `box(flt1)`. How do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind button object with any method so that whenever button get pressed that event get called.
for example,

```
import wx
class Example(wx.Frame):
    self.flt1 = NumCtrl(self, pos, size)
    self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, label, pos, size)
    self.btn1.bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, btn1Click)

    def btn1Click(self,event):
        self.flt1.GetValue()
```